# How do I set up a geospatial 2dsphere index on field that is an array?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I am trying to use geospatial 2dsphere on an field that is an array of coordinates.

I have cities with areas and each city has its own array of areas. When I try to do an intersection, i test myArea only with the areas of a particular city. Thus, I don't want to put ALL AREAS from all cities in the same collection.

Thus my question, how do you set this up?

My server is nodejs and i use native mongodb lib, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoJSON does define a [MultiPoli](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#multipolygon) datatype, which has been implemented in [recent releases of MongoDB](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8907).  If you can't use one of these versions, you can workaround, by creating a document for each city in one collection, and a document for each Polygon associated to a city in another collection while storing the id of the original city.

i.e.

city Collection:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("51f67cfb20ea59dba539d9f8"),
    name: 'New York',
    ...
}
```

city_polys Collection

```
{
    city_id: ObjectId("51f67cfb20ea59dba539d9f8"),
    loc: {
            type: Polygon,
            coordinates: ...
    },
    ...
}
```

You can then create a 2dsphere index on the city_poly's loc field.

Comment: while I made a workaround by doing the intersection in nodejs (server) but your answer is acceptable. cheers.

Comment: It's worth nothing that support for MultiPoli ([SERVER-8907](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8907)) has currently only been added to the 2.5 development/unstable release of MongoDB, so is planned for the 2.6 production release later in the year.